# finding numbers that aren't prime in Matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave, primes

I know I can find prime numbers less than or equal to 25 using the `primes` function:

```
p = primes(25)
p=2    3    5    7   11   13   17   19   23
```

But how can I find numbers that aren't prime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it a number of different ways.

Here's two approaches

```
a = setdiff([1:25],primes(25))
```

OR

```
a = find(~isprime([1:25]))
```

Comment: You can make an anonymous function of it: `noprimes=@(x)(setdiff([1:x],primes(x)))` which can be used `noprimes(25)`